# How to pass a PHP variable using the URL

Tags: php, url

I want to pass some PHP variables using the URL.

I tried the following code:

link.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$a='Link1';
$b='Link2';
echo '<a href="pass.php?link=$a">Link 1</a>';
echo '<br/>';
echo '<a href="pass.php?link=$b">Link 2</a>';
?></body></html>`</pre></code>

pass.php
<pre><code>`<html>
<body>
<?php
if ($_GET['link']==$a)
{
echo "Link 1 Clicked";
} else {
echo "Link 2 Clicked";
}
?></body></html>
```

Upon clicking the links `Link1` and `Link2`, I get "Link 2 clicked". Why?

Comment: look at the url on the pass.php page, notice anything??

Comment: yes the variables were missing(not displayed in url)....fixed the problem

Comment: You can do it like this:
```
<a href="./gemsPack.php?uid=<?php echo $id; ?>&amount=1.99">
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your link.php your `echo` statement must be like this:

```
echo '<a href="pass.php?link=' . $a . '>Link 1</a>';
echo '<a href="pass.php?link=' . $b . '">Link 2</a>';
```

Then in your pass.php you cannot use `$a` because it was not initialized with your intended string value.

You can directly compare it to a string like this:

```
if($_GET['link'] == 'Link1')
```

Another way is to initialize the variable first to the same thing you did with link.php. And, a much better way is to include the `$a` and `$b` variables in a single PHP file, then include that in all pages where you are going to use those variables as Tim Cooper mention on his post. You can also include this in a session.

Answer (score 6):

You're passing `link=$a` and `link=$b` in the hrefs for A and B, respectively. They are treated as strings, not variables. The following should fix that for you:

```
echo '<a href="pass.php?link=' . $a . '">Link 1</a>';

// and

echo '<a href="pass.php?link=' . $b . '">Link 2</a>';
```

The value of `$a` also isn't included on `pass.php`. I would suggest making a common variable file and include it on all necessary pages.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution in "[Super useful bits of PHP, Form and JavaScript code](https://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/compsci/form.html)" at Skytopia.

Inside "page1.php" or "page1.html":

```
// Send the variables myNumber=1 and myFruit="orange" to the new PHP page...
<a href="page2c.php?myNumber=1&myFruit=orange">Send variables via URL!</a> 

    //or as I needed it.
    <a href='page2c.php?myNumber={$row[0]}&myFruit={$row[1]}'>Send variables</a>
```

Inside "page2c.php":

```
<?php
    // Retrieve the URL variables (using PHP).
    $num = $_GET['myNumber'];
    $fruit = $_GET['myFruit'];
    echo "Number: ".$num."  Fruit: ".$fruit;
?>
```

Comment: you should consider to ad a reference

Comment: could you explain how this works?? myNumber={$row[0]} i am unable to retrieve this value

Comment: See "[How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)". Giving proper attribution to information borrowed from other sites is very important on SO.

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers are correct, but I noticed something very important. Leaving a space between the variable and the equal sign might result in a problem. For example, `(?variablename =value)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this easy method

```
  $a='Link1';
  $b='Link2';
  echo "<a href=\"pass.php?link=$a\">Link 1</a>";
  echo '<br/>';
  echo "<a href=\"pass.php?link=$b\">Link 2</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this:

```
<a href="./gemsPack.php?uid=<?php echo $id; ?>&amount=1.99">
```

Answer (score 0):

just put

```
$a='Link1';
$b='Link2';
```

in your pass.php and you will get your answer and do a double quotation in your link.php:

```
echo '<a href="pass.php?link=' . $a . '">Link 1</a>';
```