# Passing content between tags to next page

Tags: php, variables, hyperlink

I have content between an `<a>` tag and I want to pass its content into a variable on the next page when it is clicked.

```
<a class="stuff" href="process.php"> Content One </a>
<a class="stuff" href="process.php"> Content Two </a>
<a class="stuff" href="process.php"> Content Three </a>
```

So if the middle link was clicked, the value passed to a variable in process.php would be Content Two. Can anyone help me out with that? I'm a little new to php.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing php variable using url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440197/passing-php-variable-using-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use Jquery. You could disable the default action for clicking a link. You can then use javascript to redirect to the page intended with the GET variable automatically added on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('a').click(function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
               var link = $(this).attr('href');
               var text = $(this).text();
               var url = link + '?string=' + text;
               window.location = url;
            });
         });
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! thank you. I was looking for something dynamic like this.

Answer (score 1):

Put a GET parameter behind the script name

```
<a class="stuff" href="process.php?content=Content%20Two"> Content Two </a>
```

In the script

```
echo $_GET['content'];
```

other way to put a variable to a script. Otherwise you have to make a form around that and send it with a hidden field for example.

Comment: if you want to pass it programmatically the text use `this.text()`

Comment: I mean if Content Two is like static so if you want you can replace it with jquery $(this).text();