# Passing values to URL and using them in search

Tags: php, html, mysql, e-commerce, faceted-search

**Introduction:**

I am making a very simple E Commerce website and i am stuck with the facet navigation problem, Many sites around the net are using this technique, where a user can shrink down his choice by selecting brand,color, size or price range etc. I am using raw PHP, just a test run for my my website.

I have displayed my Filters on the left side lets say (BRAND/TYPE/COLOR) and i have given them an anchor

**Brand**

```
 <a href="index.php?brand=nike">NIKE</a>
```

**Color**

```
    <a href="index.php?color=blue">Blue</a>
    <a href="index.php?color=white">White</a>
```

**Type**

```
    <a href="index.php?type=shoe">Shoe</a>
    <a href="index.php?type=shirt">Shirt</a>
```

As you can see i am passing my values one by one and in my PHP Code, i am using below query to make

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM products ";


// add fileters e.g. from $_GET array
$i = 0;

foreach($filter_array as $filter -> $filter_value)
{
   if( ! $i)
   {
      $sql_query .= "WHERE ";
   }
   else
   {
      $sql_query .= " AND ";
   }

   $sql_query .= $fliter . " = '" . $filter_value . "'";

   $i++;       
}
```

**QUESTION**
How can i get multiple values in URL and read them and use them in my select query. Please suggest:

```
 www.abc.com/index.php?brand=nike&color=blue&type=shoe
```

**Bonus Question :)**
After using above filters,how can i use the price range thing in my page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the sql query using get values, you can use below code:

I have used "echo $query . $condition;" to check query

```
$cnt = count($_GET);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$condition = "";
if($cnt > 0){
    $condition .= " WHERE ";
}
$i = 0;
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    $condition .= $key."=".$value;
    $i++;
    if($i < ($cnt)){
            $condition .= " AND ";
    }

}
echo $query . $condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

The pure html solution would be to create links that pass more than one variables at the same time. [How to pass multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440197/passing-php-variable-using-url). What I think it's better is to use a bit of Javascript in order to achieve this.

What you are currently doing, is to pass one variable in the URL each time you click on a link.

What I would do is to modify the onclick event of my a tags so once they are clicked they modify the url of the page to add an extra element, and possibly submit the form.

Are you using any javascript framework?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the HREF tag we need to solve this with javascript. Using Jquery and the data attribute we can add the types we want and remember them.

In the example I made here I fetch the current attributes from the URL, store them in a JS object and then add the click value to create the new URL. All you need to do after that is redirect the user to that URL.

You can also extract these parameters in PHP off course and use the href attribute and dynamically add them. But here is a JS example.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  var URLparameters = getURLParameters("http://www.test.com?brand=nike");
  
  var filter = {type: URLparameters['type'], color: URLparameters['color'], brand: URLparameters['brand']};
  
  filter[$(this).data('type')] = $(this).data('value');
 
  //this is simplified off course you need to make this into a function that loops over all properties
  var newUrl = "http://www.test.com?type=nike".split("?")[0] + "?type=" + filter.type + "&brand=" + filter.brand + "&color=" + filter.color;
  
  alert(newUrl);
  
});
  
  
function getURLParameters(url){

    var result = {};
    var searchIndex = url.indexOf("?");
    if (searchIndex == -1 ) return result;
    var sPageURL = url.substring(searchIndex +1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {       
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');      
        result[sParameterName[0]] = sParameterName[1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li style="list-style-type: none;">
    <h1>Brand</h1>
    <p>
      <a data-type="brand" data-value="nike" href="#">NIKE</a>
    </p>
  </li>

  <li style="list-style-type: none;">
    <h1>Color</h1>
    <p>
      <a data-type="color" data-value="blue" href="#">Blue</a>
      <br/>
      <a data-type="color" data-value="white" href="#">White</a>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li style="list-style-type: none;">
    <h1>Type</h1>
    <p>
      <a data-type="type" data-value="shoe" href="#">Shoe</a>
      <br/>
      <a data-type="type" data-value="shirt" href="#">Shirt</a>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```