# How to utilize the Ajax call success return data to php code for running mysql query in same file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am getting data from ajax call. But that data is coming in Jquery and I have saved it in a variable. Now I want that data to be utilized for running some php and mysql code. Can any one solve this?

```
 $("#submit_bt").click(function () {
    var name = $('#search-box').val();
    var dataString = 'name=' + name;

    if (name == "" ){
         $('.alert').show().html('Please fill all information')
    }
    else
    {             
         // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "read_data.php",
             data: dataString,
             cache: false,
             success: function (result) {
                     alert(result);
                 //$('.alert').show().html(result).delay(2000).fadeOut(3000);
                 setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "index.php";},2000);
             }

         });

     }
 return result;
 });
```

Comment: You could call your index.php with parameters

Comment: Can you tell me in some detail what exactly you are saying

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440197/passing-php-variable-using-url
It is explained there how to pass parameters to your index.php (your php code you want to execude which inserts values into the database)
Edit: Sorry, linked the wrong question, now it should be correct

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to navigate to the index.php page on click of that button, then, do it this way:

```
$("#submit_bt").click(function () {
    var name = $('#search-box').val();
    var dataString = 'name=' + name;

    if (name == "" ){
         $('.alert').show().html('Please fill all information')
    }
    else
    {             
     // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "read_data.php",
         data: dataString,
         cache: false,
         success: function (result) {
                 alert(result); //you may remove this. use console.log for debugging your js next time
             setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "index.php?result="+result;},2000); //why the timeout?
         }

     });

     }
 });
```

Comment: I am trying to implement the above code. But it is again going to index.php without the above window location. How to get that data in php file can u pls help me out on that.

Comment: I suspect your `#submit_bt` is in a form and is performing the default behaviour of submitting the form. What you should do is set the `type` attribute of the button to `button`. I think it's `type='submit` by default. Let me know how you fare

Answer (score 0):

The easier and proper solution should be to re-use ajax to use this variable in another PHP file.

```
$("#submit_bt").click(function () {
var name = $('#search-box').val();
var dataString = 'name=' + name;

if (name == "" ){
     $('.alert').show().html('Please fill all information')
}
else
{             
     // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "read_data.php",
         data: dataString,
         cache: false,
         success: function (result) 
         {
             //AJAX code to execute your MySQL query
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "read_data2.php",
                 data: result,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) 
                 {
                     //Manage your read_data2.php output
                 }
             });
         }
     });
 }
```