# PHP Pass variable price text value to next page

Tags: php, jquery

i have a price form like that. All the things are working but i couldnt make the total price show on next page.

```
       <!-- packs -->
    <div class="packs" >
                 <div class="item" id="packs-1" rel='1'
                 data-commission='2' data-price='10'>
                <span>10 usd</span>
            </div>
                  <div class="item" id="packs-2" rel='2'
                 data-commission='3' data-price='25'>
                <span>25 usd</span>
            </div>
                 <div class="item" id="packs-3" rel='3'
                 data-commission='4' data-price='50'>
                <span>50 usd</span>
            </div>
                 <div class="item" id="packs-4" rel='4'
                 data-commission='4' data-price='100'>
                <span>100 usd</span>
            </div>
                 <div class="item" id="packs-8" rel='8'
                 data-commission='4' data-price='250'>
                <span>250 usd</span>
            </div>
                 <div class="item" id="packs-12" rel='12'
                 data-commission='5' data-price='500'>
                <span>500 usd</span>
            </div>

        <div class="total">
            <span>Main Price : <b class="mainprice" id='mainprice'>0 usd</b></span>
            <span>Tax Price : <b class="taxes" id='taxes'>0 usd</b></span>
            <span class="Total" >Total Price: <b class="Total" id='Total' >0 usd</b></span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the example how i want.

```
            <div class="total">
            <span>Main Price : <b class="mainprice" id='mainprice'>25 usd (total price selected) </b></span>
            <span>Tax Price : <b class="taxes" id='taxes'>2 usd (automatic calculated tax 2 usd) </b></span>
            <span class="Total" >Total Price: <b class="Total" id='Total' >27 usd (that is total price)</b></span>

        </div>
```

Form and tax calculate works perfectly. Just my question is how can i pass 27 usd value pass to echo another page?

here is my calculate code

```
<script>
$(".item").click(function() {
    var price = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price'));
    var commission = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-commission'));
    var total = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(commission);

    $("form[name='payment-form'] input.vds-products").val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $("#mainprice").html(price + ' usd');
    $("#taxes").html(commission + ' usd');
    $("#Total").html(total + ' usd');

});
```

here is all php full 3 files.
[Dropbox full php files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/or42ojmt2mxq6gl/AAC0VjDFrxbpIdhOQJ1SvRnla?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it with link and use get method on another page to get the total price like here [Pass variable using php url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440197/passing-php-variable-using-url)

Comment: at the end i have submit button link doesnt work for me :( or could you show me sample? another name, mail etc infos showing on next page, only that price doesnt show :(

Comment: in dropbox i put 3 php file. index.php, session.php and succes.php. all data pass another page just price doesnt :(  here is the link : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/or42ojmt2mxq6gl/AAC0VjDFrxbpIdhOQJ1SvRnla?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Why note use session (would be my personal decision) or pass the total by post-request to the next page? Note: passing vars by post or get is dangerous, they could be manipulated. But no one is able to touch the $_SESSION var.

Comment: Assuming that you are using jquery to calculate the prices:

    Send simple POST passing your value to a file named session.php 
    `$.post( "session.php", { total: "99.99"} );`

    session.php contains: 
    `<?PHP 
        session_start(); 
        if(isset($_POST['total'])) {
            if(!isset($_SESSION['total'])) { $_SESSION['total'] = 0; }
            $_SESSION['total'] = (float)$_POST['total']; 
        }        
    ?>`

Comment: And in your second file, do 
    `<?PHP session_start(); echo (isset($_SESSION['total']) ? $_SESSION['total'] : '0.00'); ?>`

    dont forget to change the file extension in your secind file to .php 

    Good luck.

Comment: index i use <?php 
$.post( "session.php", { total: "99.99"} );
?> i got HTTP ERROR 500 any solution for it. :)

Comment: this is the jquery - part

Comment: okay it worked but i got echo Total 99.99 in second page:( i wanted variable price to show up 2. page :[ that user choice and price changes auto. any solution for it too :[

Comment: here is my jq script for calculate price if that helps. <script>
    $(".item").click(function() {
        var price = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price'));
        var commission = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-commission'));
        var total = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(commission);

        $("form[name='payment-form'] input.vds-products").val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $("#mainprice").html(price + ' usd');
        $("#taxes").html(commission + ' usd');
        $("#Total").html(total + ' usd');

    });
</script>

Comment: ok, please replace my *placeholder* of "99.99" with your JS-var "total". So, add this at the bottom of your script: `$.post( "session.php", { total:total } );` .

Comment: well i did what u have said :D still getting 99.99 at 2. page. i have changed $.post( "session.php", { total:total} ) code page 1 and rest same soo, idk :D