# Sending a php variable in URL(get method)

Tags: php, html, get, getmethod

I want to send a value using the get method. The code is something like this

```
<td><a href="cart-remove.php?id={$row['id']}" class="remove_item_link"> Remove</a></td>
```

This value i want to send is stored in $row['id'].This is not my code its from my instructor (very popular website with around 30k people having enrolled in the course so far but i can't name them here), see this 
[image: instructors question]

but if i type exactly like he/she did i will get this error. 
[image]

Found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18625762/10976207) on stackoverflow (from 2013). But when i use it like this

```
<?php

$id=$_GET['id'];
echo "hey".$id;
```

I get a output like this `hey{$row['id']}`

I have tried this but it doesn't work either

```
<td><a href="cart-remove.php?id={$row[\'id\']}" class="remove_item_link"> Remove</a></td>
```

How do i get this value in the cart-remove.php page? I know answers some from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5440197/10976207) question work but i am trying to keep my code similar to my instructors code as he is gonna rate the project. Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18625762/10976207)(mentioned above) was from the same thread.

Comment: `<td><a href="cart-remove.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>" class="remove_item_link"> Remove</a></td>` No? or didn’t I understand the question ?!

Comment: @ScreamX Thank you it worked. But i still don't understand why my instructor and that answer from 7 years ago use `{}` instead of `<? >`. Is there some way that works too?? That method got deprecated or something?

Comment: I think he mean something like that: `<?php echo "<a href='page2c.php?myNumber={$array1}&myFruit={$array2}'>Send variables</a>"; ?>`

Comment: @ScreamX used it like this <?php echo " <a href='cart-remove.php?id={$row['id']}' class='remove_item_link'> Remove</a>" ?> It works.Please post your complete answer so i can mark it as accepted answer. You deserve much love <3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the request of the author of the topic.
All the plain HTML in your code will be ignored by the PHP compiler and passed to the web browser unchanged, so you need to open the `<?php` handler.

```
<td><a href="cart-remove.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>" class="remove_item_link"> Remove</a></td>
```

and your instructor probably meant the following conclusion:

```
<?php echo "<td><a href='cart-remove.php?id={$row['id']}' class='remove_item_link'> Remove</a></td>"; ?>
```

but, this will only work if the text is already in the php handler

Comment: single inverted comma for href and class attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it would only work if this were part of an `echo` statement with a double-quoted string. But you're outputting the HTML direectly, not with `echo`, so you can't use string concanation or substitution.

You need to do it the same way all the other `$row` elements were embedded on previous lines of the script.

```
<td><a href="cart-remove.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="remove_item_link"> Remove</a></td>
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine. I ran it when ScreamX commented. But i still don't understand why my instructor and that answer from 7 years ago use {} instead of <? >. Is there some way that works too?? That method got deprecated or something?

Comment: The instructor made a mistake. He also said "inside single quotes", but variable substitution only works inside double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your time. It seems if you're already inside echo you can use both of those stuff `{}` and `' '`.   But this problem page was 6 pages long, I think my instructor did miss out on stuff XD.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><a href="cart-remove.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>" class="remove_item_link"> Remove</a></td>
```