# How to pass values via anchor tag to filter function?

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

I am making a special page that has href links to cars that have special rates on them. For example $100 payment credit for a sedan. I have a filter section another page that looks like this.

```
$resultsSQL = "SELECT * FROM newcars WHERE new=1";
if (isset($_POST['body'])) {
          $body = implode("','", $_POST['body']);
          $resultsSQL .= " AND body IN('" . $body . "')";
      }
```

How could I pass this parameter on through a href link so when you click the link on another page it already has the sedan body styling selected?

Comment: have you tried something? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440197/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-using-the-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440197/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-using-the-url) take a look

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the href links, you would need to use $_GET instead of $_POST. Your links would like like this

`https://mywebsite.com?body=Something`

If you node the `body=[VALUE]` is added after the `?` that is added after the website page `https://mywebsite.com`. This allows you to pass data via the query string and get request.

Your link may look like this:

```
<a href="https://mywebsite.com?body=Something">Something Important</a>
```

On another note, I recommend that you perform additional checks in PHP to protect your application against other security concerns, eg. [SQL injection](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi49MTZ7-npAhX0l3IEHdC6A58QFjAJegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSQL_injection&usg=AOvVaw1uzN238Ma4U7MFZg35w2eA)

Comment: How exactly would I need to set that up on specials page before passing it through, I tried doing it like this but the data isn't passing through.`<?php
              $resultsSQL = "SELECT * FROM newcars WHERE new=1";

             if (isset($_POST['body'])) {
              $body = implode("','", $_POST['body']);
              $resultsSQL .= " AND body IN('" . $body . "')";
          }
              ?>
              <a class="offer-image-link" href="new-vehicles.php?body=sedan">
              <img src="img/service-page/1.jpg">
              </a>`

Comment: I have also tried it like this                                                                                            `<?php
                $resultSQL = "SELECT * FROM NEWCARS WHERE body=sedan";
                if (isset($_GET['body'])) {
                    $body = implode("','", $_GET['body']);
                    $resultsSQL .= " AND body IN('" . $body . "')";
                }
                echo "<a class='offer-image-link' href='new-vehicles.php?body=sedan#s'>";
                echo "img/service-page/GLA.jpg";
                echo "</a>"
              ?>`