# How can I dynamically assign a separate id to each div in HTML/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I am new to webdesign and I created a mySQL database on a webserver that holds a table with a number of ToDos. I then use PHP to load that table from the mySQL database and create a div for each ToDo on a webpage. I am struggling with the next step i.e. give each div a different color based on the urgency of the ToDo, which is coded as an integer in the mySQL table. I figured I need to specify a different ID depending on the urgency, so when showing the div, HTML would give it the correct color by using the correct style as associated to the id.

```
<html>
    <head>

    <style>

        #fenster{
            width : 200px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        #zeile{
            height: 40px;
            width: 300px;
            border: thin solid gray;
            border-top: thick solid red;
            margin: 5px;
            text-overflow: hidden;
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left;
            font-size: 1.0rem;
        }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #zeile{
        height: 115px;
        width: 270px;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        margin: 1rem;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
}

        .kaestchen {
        color: red;
        }


</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxxx","xxx","xxxx");
$sqlCom = 'SELECT name FROM zeilen';
$requ = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCom);
$personen = mysqli_fetch_all($requ, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<div>
<div>
    <?php foreach($personen as $person){ ?>

        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div id=zeile left=100px onclick=window.location.href='edit.php?itemID=20'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($person['name']); ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

What I think I need to do is find a way to dynamically assign a separate id to each div which would allow me to control the color of the div e.g. id=urg0, id=urg1 etc. Also I would like to pass the id of the ToDo to an "edit"-page so I think I have to create another PHP page that would load the data for this specific ToDo from the databse for editing and getting the id passed as parameter. In my example, this is a fixed number because I could not figure out a way to make this number be the counter variable.

Do I need to use Javascript for such "complicated" operations??

--- I tried to implement the suggestion so I changed my code to:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>

            .urgency-0{
            width: 300px;
            float: left;
            border-top: thick solid black;
            }.urgency-1{
            width: 300px;
            float: left;
            border-top: thick solid blue;
            }
            .urgency-2{
            width: 300px;
            float: left;
            border-top: thick solid green;
            }
            .urgency-3{
            width: 300px;
            float: left;
            border-top: thick solid yellow;
            }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxx","xxxxx","xxxxx");
$sqlCom = 'SELECT * FROM zeilen';
$requ = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCom);
$personen = mysqli_fetch_all($requ, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<div>
<div>
<?php> $counter = 0; ?>
     <?php foreach($personen as $person){ ?>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="urgency-"+<?php echo htmlspecialchars($person['urgency']); ?> left=100px onclick=window.location.href='edit.php?itemID=$counter'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($person['name']); ?></div>
                    <?php $counter++; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

It seems I am still doing something wrong.

Comment: Can multiple todo items have the same level of `urgency`?

Comment: yes, I am planning on urgency levels of 0 to 5, so all the items will be grouped into either one of the six urgency groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Javascript needed.

One way is to define one css rule per urgency.

Using classes on your divs as `<div class="urgency-x">`, where x is the urgency number

```css
<head>
<style>
.urgency-1 {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.urgency-2 {
  background-color: #BBBBBB;
}
.urgency-n {
  background-color: #111111;
}
</style>
</head>
```

The above shows the rules defined in the head as you have it. Obviously, you could have those in a .css file, but that is another story.

You can still write your css rules to match on id's, but those id's are typically used to set elements apart, so it would be unusual to have more than one element with the same id. Classes are to categorize elements in a way, so using classes is more typical for the use case you are providing.

Another way is to set the `style` on your div like `<div style="background-color: #CCCCCC;">`

As far as passing the todo ID to another page goes, you would presumably have some sort or ui element that the user "clicks" on to navigate to the edit page. A very basic example is an anchor

`<a href="edit.php?id=5">Edit me</a>`

Here is a question that addressed that on the php side [How to pass a PHP variable using the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440197/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-using-the-url)

Comment: I included the style directly into the code because for some reason I observed that when making changes to an external .css file, the website seems to use old versions of the .css file even though I changed and uploaded newer versions to the server. I did not figure out how to make my browser use the new .css file instead of the one it seems to have memorized somehow.

Comment: Dear M. Gallant,  I tried to implement your suggestions and changed my code. I show this as an edit in my question above.

Comment: I found my mistake. It works, now!